# how to put UITablev\View inside method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I created `UItableView` programatically (not by draging), now on click of button I want to call `UITableView`. How should I call ?

in .h file

```
UITableView *aTableView
```

Comment: on click of button you need to vall tableview in the same page ah

Answer (score 0):

use tag property of uitable. then you can refer it.